# "Where do you think she got the pills from?" vs "Where did you think she got the pills?" vs "Where did you think she gets the pills?"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

"Where do you think she got the pills?"
"Where did you think she got the pills?"
"Where did you think she gets the pills?"

Which one is the correct sentence if I ask someone about an accident about a girl that swallowed pills and the girl is now still unconscious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three are possible. Which one you prefer really depends on the context.

Assuming that the girl who took the pills is unconscious (and thus unlikely to get any more pills, at least for a while, the most likely question is:

> **Where do you think she got the pills (that have caused her to fall ill)?**

If on the other hand you assume that she has made of habit of consuming the pills, it would be fair to ask:

> **Where do you think she gets the pills?**

The other option **Where did you think....?** is likely only as a response to something that someone else has said:

> A: Do you mean that my son may have been involved in this?
> B: **(I'm afraid so.) Where did you think she got the pills?**

Comment: Okay, I understand it. Where do you think she got the pills is the correct sentense for my case. Thank you. It's really helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want to ask:

> "Where do you think she got the pills?"

If you are interested in where your informant used to think, or once thought, the girl (sometimes or regularly) got the pills, ask:

> "Where *did* you think she got the pills?"

If you are interested in where your informant used to think, or once thought, the girl (on this occasion) had got the pills, ask:

> "Where *did* you think she had got the pills?"

If you are interested in where your informant used to think the girl still, even today, gets the pills, ask:

> "Where did you think she gets the pills?"

Comment: I don't really understand about how you use did. I thought did is for past tense but in my case, the girl had the pills last night and right now she is unconscious.

Comment: You're right. 'did' is for the past tense. There are two verbs here: think and get. So there are four possibilities: Where **do** you think she **gets**, Where **did** you think she **gets**, Where **do** you think she **got**, Where **did** you think she **got**. Sorry if I made it too complicated! You've chosen the right sentence.

Comment: Nah, it's okay. I still struggle with English and sometimes it took some times for me to understand it correctly. Besides I never knew there could be four possibilities with the two verbs. It's also something new I have learnt for today. Thank you for sharing with me.